# Equal height for children in HStack { ... } with specified AspectRatio

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swiftui

SwiftUI 2.0 | Swift 5.4 | Xcode 12.4 | macOS Big Sur 11.3

I'm trying to get dynamically the same height for children in an HStack, but I cannot achieve that without by adding frame constraints:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Box(aspectRatio: 1.5)
            Box(aspectRatio: 1.5)
            Box(aspectRatio: 1.5)
            Box(aspectRatio: 0.8)
            Box(aspectRatio: 0.8)
        }
    }
}

struct Box: View {
    var aspectRatio: CGFloat
    
    var body: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5, style: .continuous)
            .fill(Color.blue)
            .aspectRatio(aspectRatio, contentMode: .fit)
    }
}
```

I'm getting this:

[image]

But I want to achieve this:

[image]

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-make-two-views-the-same-width-or-height

Comment: @tohidmahmoudvand Yeap, the problem is that you have to know the height of the row (that depends on the aspect ratio of the elements, width of the screen, spacing between elements), that doesn't do things so easy.